# Why does "repeated measures" not appear under "analyze - glm" menu in SPSS?

Tags: spss

This is my first time using SPSS for doing within-subjects ANOVA. Every tutorial I see tells me that I should go to analyze -> General Linear Model -> Repeated Measures.

The problem is that under "General Linear Model" the only command I see is "Univariate". Why can't I find "Repeated Measures"? I'm using SPSS 21.

Comment: This because you don't have "Advanced module" installed. SPSS comes of a dozen modules. You probably have only Basic module installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the organization of SPSS.

Answer (score 3):

As @ttnphns states, you need to obtain and install the [Avanced Statistics](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/spss-advanced-stats) add-on module.
It includes a range of additional modelling tools like GLMs, mixed models, etc.

SPSS divides up its packages into Base and a range of add-on modules. The add-on modules are often automatically bundled in various packages. For example, a quick look at [the gradpack](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/spss-stats-gradpack/) shows a range of different versions some that come with the "advanced statistics" add-on and others that don't:

> - IBM SPSS Statistics Base GradPack offers beginners the most frequently used procedures for statistical analysis, and includes IBM
>     SPSS Statistics Base, which provides the foundation for many types of
>     analyses. [i.e., no advanced stats]
> - IBM SPSS Statistics Standard GradPack enables intermediate students to use more advanced analytical algorithms and techniques, and
>     includes IBM SPSS Statistics Base, **IBM SPSS Advanced Statistics**, IBM
>     SPSS Regression.